# My discord bot is responding only to DMs but not in channels

Tags: python, discord

somehow my bot is not responding to commands in servers, but he is responding in DM. Someone can help me?

My code:

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
token = "****"
load_dotenv()
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default() )

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot logged in as {client.user}")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:
        if message.content =='$hi':
            d = "hi"
            await message.channel.send(d)

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default Intent value is `3243773` which doesn't have `GUILD_MEMBERS`, `GUILD_PRESENCES` and `MESSAGE_CONTENT` intents.
One of these (most likely `MESSAGE_CONTENT`) means that your bot isn't sent the content of messages in servers. You can test this by just printing `message.content` and you should just see empty messages.
To fix you can use discord.Intents.all() which has all intents

```py
# add some/all of these to see what works
client = discord.Client(intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

quick note: you can make your code cleaner  by removing an indent level

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user: return;
    if message.content =='$hi':
        d = "hi"
        await message.channel.send(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
token = "BOT_TOKEN"

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot logged in as {client.user}")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:

        if message.content == '$hi':
            d = "hi"
            await message.channel.send(d)

client.run(token)
```

And enable all Privileged Gateway Intents in Discord Developer Poral > App Name > Bot > Privileged Gateway Intents. If you need any help developing your discord bot or need some other help related to coding then message me on discord RobertK#6151!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2EI6.png